# Layout vs. non-Layout panels in UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

From reading the GWT documentation I know that "layout" panels such as DockLayoutPanel are for *standards* mode and that "non-layout" panels such as DockPanel are for *quirks* mode.

And both classes are defined in the [UI Service API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_ui). But the UiInstance only has a createDockPanel method, no createDockLayoutPanel method?! So how do I create a layout panels? In fact, only Split Layout has a create method in UiInstance!?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, and you should file an issue on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1841).

Comment: Done, I've created [Issue 1884](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1884)